# Canonical forms for relational algebra expressions

Tags: db.databases, relational-structures, normalization

I'm looking for whatever work may exist, or thoughts people have, on the question of whether/to what extent there exist(s) one or more canonical form(s) to which relational algebra expressions may be reduced.

I'm investigating the feasability of building a relational query optimizer which allows hand-writing of query plans but proves (or assists the user in proving) that the plan satisfies the query.

If there isn't a (usefully non-enormous) canonical form, then I wouldn't know the first thing about how to attack the problem. I suppose read up on Coq or Isabelle, work on translating my equivalence question into theorem prover's language, and work on providing a less-grad-school-required interface that exposes (relevant parts of) the theorem prover's output.

If there is a canonical form that doesn't tend to blow up to enormous sizes, then of course its a much easier problem.

Comment: While I don't have a specific answer, the PODS community (PODS is the main database theory conference) has done a ton of work on these sorts of questions, and and it might be worth looking into. A good start might be the Database theory book by Abiteboul et al

Comment: @Suresh: The Alice book doesn't really go in depth. Query rewrites there are just ad-hoc rules.

Answer (score 4):

There are canonical forms, but there are not *unique* canonical forms. Roughly, the idea is to use observe that sets form a monad and use the equational theory of Moggi's monadic metalanguage as a well-behaved IR for  optimizing queries. See Torsten Grust's PhD thesis, [*Comprehending Queries*](http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/dbis/publications/download/TG-GI00.pdf).

More recently, [the Ferry Project](http://www.pathfinder-xquery.org/research/ferry) has been investigating integrating programming languages with query languages.

Comment: Great stuff. This Comprehending Queries paper is excellent. Thanks.

Comment: Ferry Project link appears broken.

Answer (score 3):

*Relational Lattice* is axiomatic foundation for *Relational Algebra*. Predictably, query transformations reduce to equational reasoning in that axiom system. Here are examples:

- [Push-select-via-project](http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0603/0603044.pdf)
- [Renaming](http://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/relational-lattice/the-laws-of-renaming/)

Many others like commutativity and associativity of [relational] join operation, or permutting selection via join are trivial in the sense that they are fundamental lattice laws.

You mentioned theorem provers; not surprisingly, some research has been facilitated with *Prover9*.

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting stuff, thanks Tegiri!